# Disable Recaptcha Component

Tags: magento, google-api, recaptcha

**Situation:**

I have a magento website with a contact page. 
I've installed an extension for google recaptcha (https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/contacts-form-captcha.html).

This all went without any problems. Now I'm testing this extension and the form looks like this:

[image]

when i check the 'I'm not a robot' checkbox. It pops to green but when I submit the form it gives me a message that the recaptcha was entered incorrectly. 
After that the oldschool captcha shows up:

[image]

After I fill in this captcha the form works well, validates, and submits the mail.

**Question:**

Is there any way I can remove the "I'm not a robot" captcha, and always display the oldschool captcha?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want text and numeric recaptcha you'll have to use a older version (v1). With the one you are using right now (v2) it is not possible to set it to Text only.

It looks like the first page doesnt validate the captcha but the second page does. It can be that you have both versions since you have v2 on page one and v1 on page 2. You should be able to delete v2 from your files or code.

Comment: I have no idea actually... i just did a quick google search to find that out.